# Placebo-worthy drug?

Tags: internal-consistency, modern-age, diseases, medicine

Are there any medicine out there specifically used to treat serious illnesses (it could be  something as simple as painkillers to something for a very rare chronic illness) that could be swapped out for a placebo or a fake alternative at a pharmacy by some kind of gang or cartel for profit on at least a town-level scale without the average, unsuspecting person (or even the pharmacy itself) finding out, at least immediately? (Such as the gang swapping in the placebo (somehow) and then reselling the drug at a drastic markup on the black market)

I was perhaps thinking pain killers, but somehow getting a pharmacy to continuously sell fake pain killers without people starting a riot seemed a tad too unrealistic to me.

The story setting is modern-day USA.

Many thanks!

Comment: Any form of homeopathy, Whatever they swap it with will be just as effective, it is pure placebo.

Comment: Any medicine given for palliative care that has no observable effects. Or where placebo is almost as effective. Or where results are "does not work for everyone". Or things that help you *cope* with viruses like e.g., HIV and Herpes. - Chemotherapy is not available at the pharmacy.

Comment: @Mazura - here is a link to bring you up to speed on oral chemo purchased thru a pharmacy.  Some of them a specific mail order pharmacy, it is true.  https://member.carefirst.com/carefirst-resources/pdf/oral-chemotherapy-drug-list-sum2714.pdf

Comment: What you describe is not a fiction, but pretty much a practice in a lot of less-developed countries. They sell diluted or outright fake antibiotics. It is probably not practical for rarely-used drugs.

Comment: @Mazura I really like the idea of coping medication too. I'll definitely look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

**Chemotherapy.**

There was a notorious case of a pharmacist who diluted chemotherapy medicines.  Chemo does not always work against cancers, and patients do not always get sick (and are happy when they do not!), so this went on for some time.  Chemo is expensive and so he made a lot of money this way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Courtney

> In 1998, Darryl Ashley, an Eli Lilly sales representative noticed
>   Courtney was selling three times the amount of the cancer drug Gemzar
>   than he'd bought. Lilly initiated an internal investigation but found
>   no evidence of illegality and closed the investigation without further
>   action.
>
> In early 2001, Ashley once again voiced his concerns to a nurse who
>   worked for Dr. Verda Hunter (now Hicks), an oncologist in Courtney's
>   building, who was also one of Courtney's customers. Hunter noticed
>   that many of her patients were only suffering mild side effects, and
>   their condition didn't seem to be improving.[4][5] Hunter had
>   medication that had been supplied by Courtney tested. That test showed
>   that the sample contained less than one-third of the drug prescribed,
>   and upon receiving the test results back, Hunter immediately notified
>   the FBI.[1][4]
>
> Investigators believed that Courtney took a base dose of chemotherapy
>   drugs and split it between three prescriptions, then sold them to
>   oncologists for the same price as a full dose. He took advantage of
>   the fact that oncologists are usually concerned mainly with
>   chemotherapy's effects on the body, not the amount of the dose.[4]

There are more recent allegations of this sort of thing in Mexico:
https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-38675688 - diluting the chemo or just using some harmless IV solution and saying it is chemotherapy.

Avastin is another cancer fighting drug and there was a recent case of exactly what you describe - organized criminals selling fake Avastin.
https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2012/02/15/146929475/fda-warns-about-fake-avastin-in-us

Comment: This is wonderful thank you! I'd upvote, but I don't have the rep yet haha.
But one last question: Do you have any idea how an average person can tell if said medicine is fake, minus checking the label for foreign writing and whatnot? I don't live in the US so I don't know if you can send medicine to testing facilities or anything...

Comment: The manufacturer could test it if asked.  They have to run quality control on their own stuff and they are ready to get a questionable batch returned and analyze it.  A pharmacist used to the real stuff might tell if it did not dissolve right, wrong color etc.  It would be really hard to tell with a biologic drug like Avastin.